# How to implement image button on OSX in RubyMotion?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, macos, cocoa, rubymotion

This strikes me as something that should be incredibly easy, but I just can't get it to work.

I'm creating a button as such:

```
closeButton = NSButton.alloc.initWithFrame(
    [[10, 10], [100, 22]]
  ).tap do |button|
    button.bezelStyle = NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle
    button.buttonType = NSMomentaryChangeButton
    button.title = 'Close'
    button.bordered = false
    button.image = NSImage.imageNamed('img/circle')
    p button.image
    button.imagePosition = NSImageOnly
    button.target = window
    button.action = 'close'
  end
```

There are 2 images, `circle.png` and `circle@2x.png`, stored in `/Resources/img`.

Needless to say, I get a gray button with no text or image within it. Also, `p button.image` returns `nil`.

I've cleaned and rebuilt my project a number of times.

This doesn't seem like it should be so difficult to implement. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I sort of figured this out. It would appear that either `imageNamed` doesn't work the way I'm expecting, or I'm simply using it incorrectly.

I was able to set an image on a button by doing the following:

```
NSButton.alloc.initWithFrame(
    [[110, 10], [100, 22]]
).tap do |button|
    neutralImgPath = NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource("img/circle2", ofType: "png")
    neutralImgUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(neutralImgPath)
    neutralImg = NSImage.alloc.initWithContentsOfURL(neutralImgUrl)

    button.setImage(neutralImg)

    button.setImageScaling(NSImageScaleProportionallyDown)
    button.setImagePosition(NSImageOnly)

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.bordered = false
    button.bezelStyle = NSShadowlessSquareBezelStyle
    button.buttonType = NSMomentaryChangeButton

    button.target = MainAppWindow.get
    button.action = 'minimize:'
end
```

Would definitely love to figure out a more concise way to do this, but for now, it gets the job done!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let me say I have zero experience with OSX, but I'm hoping this iOS info will help.  I've been told they are pretty identical.  You need to make sure you're using a custom button (UIButtonTypeCustom).  This will allow you to use background image abilities.

Here's some good example code, that might help you out.

https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubymotion_cookbook/tree/master/ch_2/16_buttons

Again, I'm sorry if this doesn't do the job, but I figure I'd post this info to help!

Comment: Thanks for replying! Sadly, UIButtonTypeCustom doesn't seem to exist in the OSX API. Appreciate it, though.